# svn: E000002: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: linux, apache, svn

I'm trying to install svn to my linux (raspberry pi).

What I've done:

Installed Subversion

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Createed a directory to hold the repositories

```
mkdir -p  /mnt/usbdrive/svn/
```

Created a new repository

```
svnadmin create /home/pi/repos/vladimir
```

Installed apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-svn
```

Modified the file /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /home/pi/repos
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repo"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Restarted Apache to pick up the config

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Changed the permissions of the repos directory

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/pi/repos
```

Created an svn user

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd alex
```

Now I'm trying to test my SVN

```
svn co --username alex http://localhost/svn/vladimir
```

And I've got this error

```
svn: E000002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL http://localhost/svn/vladimir
svn: E000002: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

The permission for svn repository is:

pi@raspberrypi /mnt/usbdrive/svn $ ls -lart

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root     4096 Mar  9 11:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  9 13:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  9 13:28 vladimir
```

What is wrong with my SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dav_svn.conf you define SVNPath not SVNParentPath. SVNPath mut be set to /home/pi/repos and then change `<Location /svn>` to `<Location /repos>`

Answer (score 0):

should be added in a conf file with same name as the repository you have created.
As you have created repository by "svnadmin create /home/pi/repos/**vladimir**", you should have conf file as "/etc/apache2/sites-available/vladimir.conf". 
But you have created it in file /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf, which is wrong.
Hope this is helpful for somebody